# How to give Root privileges for User in Centos 6.2 minimal

Tags: centos, sudoedit

I installed Centos 6.2 minimal x86_64 server in Virtual Machine Manager. After installed I created Username in the server. And I added the User into a wheel group.

```
    # useradd testuser
    # passwd testuser

    # usermod -aG wheel testuser
```

Now my problem is, I want to give the root privileges to the User which I created. Some websites given that edit the sudoers file. But sudoers file is not under the /etc folder.

Where is the Sudoers file in Centos 6.2 & How to give the Root privileges to the User.

Comment: Hey [rajcoumar](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/61108/rajcoumar) I think you should close the question by marking the answer `correct` ;D .

Answer (score 3):

Sudo is not present in the minimal ISO. You can install using:

```
yum install sudo
```